# How to call php snippet which is save as basic page?

Tags: forms

I have a php code as below:

```
$("#tbMGroup tr.odd").click(function() {
              $("#m_id").val($(this).attr("m_id"));
              $("#form1").first().attr("action", "search.php");
              $("#form1").submit();
            });
```

but,
I have add search.php to a basic page. now, these code need to call search.php when mouse click, I don't know how to call search.php snippet, because search.php now is not a independent file, it is a snippet.
Thanks for your help...

Comment: Please try to explain more cleay what you want to achieve and what the problem is?

Comment: I have add search.php to a basic page. now, these code need to call search.php when mouse click, I don't know how to call search.php file, because search.php now is not a independent file, it is a node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way, just changed my snippet to:

```
$("#tbMGroup tr.odd").click(function() {
  $("#m_id").val($(this).attr("m_id"));
  $("#form1").first().attr("action", "/node/nid");
  $("#form1").submit();
});
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use hook_menu to define the path the drupal way and rewrite your form using drupal FAPI. This gives you a clean system.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for me reference? Thank you very much..